# Can i use kubespray without kubespray_git_repo?

Tags: kubernetes

I use https://gist.github.com/ruzickap/c072cdfe480ca52bd32b6c4fcf8397a2
for deploy kubernetes

Need:

```
# Create kubespray config file
cat > ~/.kubespray.yml << EOF
kubespray_git_repo: "https://github.com/kubespray/kubespray.git"
kubespray_path: "$PWD/kubespray"
loglevel: "info"
EOF
```

Can I use kubespray without `kubespray_git_repo`, `kubespray_path` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use kubespray without kubespray_git_repo, kubespray_path ?

Without question, yes; arguably it will *most often* be used without those things (I have actually never even heard of `kubespray prepare`):

1. [download a release](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/archive/v2.5.0.tar.gz)
2. `pip install ansible` (if you don't already have ansible; you can also `brew install ansible` if you are on a Mac and/or have concerns about `pip` messing up your global pythonpath)
3. [use `ansible-playbook`](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/tree/v2.5.0#ansible)
4. declare victory